# How to set same email_address to multiple wordpress users from database

Tags: mysql, wordpress, csv, woocommerce

I am working on a wordpress/woocommerce site and using a plugin called "Import users from CSV with meta" I have imported a CSV file with 4000 customers. Since some of those customers have multiple accounts and they use the same email address I also used a plugin called "Allow multiple Accounts".

My problem is that 960/4000 users didn't contain an email address.

I would like to add a custom email address example@example.com to all 960 of them from phpMyAdmin.

Could you please help me with the code?

If I try the following I can see all the users that don't have email but I don't know how to modify all of them:

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_users` WHERE user_email = ''
```

I would really appreciate your help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

If I understood you correctly, you just need an update:

```
UPDATE wp_users SET user_email='example@example.com' WHERE user_email=''
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Exactly what I needed!